# Entity Frameworks - ToList() and 0 Records

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When expecting a recordset (>=1 record) how do you check for that 0 record situation?

For example:

```
RivWorks.Model.FeedStoreReadOnly store = new RivWorks.Model.FeedStoreReadOnly(AppSettings.FeedAutosEntities_connString, AppSettings.FeedAutosEntities_metadata, AppSettings.FeedAutosEntities_providerName);
RivWorks.Model.NegotiationAutos.Entities _dbFeed = store.ReadOnlyEntities();
var companyDetails = from a in _dbFeed.ClientClientMap where a.CompanyID == CompanyId select a;
return companyDetails.ToList();
```

When this returns it is erroring out on the ToList() because there are no records that satisfied the WHERE clause.  So, what would be the correct way to check for 0 records and what would the recommended return be at that point?

---

**Addition based off below answer**:

```
if (companyDetails.Count() > 0)
    return companyDetails.ToList();
else
{
    List<RivWorks.Model.NegotiationAutos.ClientClientMap> ret = new List<RivWorks.Model.NegotiationAutos.ClientClientMap>();
    ret.Add(companyDetails.FirstOrDefault());
    return ret;
}
```

Have not tested yet but that (logically) would seem to work.  Wondering if there is an easier way though.

---

**NOTE**:

I got it figured out.  The account that SQL was running under was not granted the correct set of permissions by the DBA.  We altered all the GRANT statements on the new tables/views and it is now working.

Am still not sure what the correct answer is though.  I am leaning towards creating a blank (new) record and adding to the List so our guys receiving the List have something to display (for edit if nothing else)...

Comment: Are you sure about the exception? it shouldn't error out, it should return a list with 0 records in it.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: On the inner exception I am getting "Invalid object name 'dbo.ClientClientMap'".  I am not understanding this error as I can see the object in my model and can reference it just fine.

Comment: I think you should remove the `ret.Add()` call, it will add a `null` to your list. You want just the empty list in the else-branch.

Comment: does not matter if I remove it or not.  The exception is being thrown anytime I access companyDetails.  i.e.:  companyDetails.Count(), companyDetails.ToList(), etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to check for empty before calling `ToList`. `ToList` works fine with a query which returns no records; it will just return an empty list. You can use your original code and everything will work fine, with or without data in the table.

Most grids and the like will also cope fine with an empty list; they'll typically display a blank row for the user to create the first record.

Answer (score 0):

ClientClientMap table is not in the database

Comment: au contrair.  It is indeed in the database and is a View.  My models are generated through the EF Wizard and I do not add any other non-database derived objects to it.  I am running into this problem with several objects that are tied to tables as well.

Comment: @Keith, perhaps your entity schema is not updated, but your exception has nothing to do with it being an empty result, to test this try to return a result with rows. Check your connection string as well, make sure you're pointing to the right database.

Comment: Permissions (SELECT/UPDATE) were not set for the account the request was running under in SQL Server (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Another cause might be that the connection string to the database contains a different database name than you intend to use. Entity Framework (if it is configured have the rights to do so) just creates a different database based on the configured connection string, and it can happen that the table you query is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, entity framework was working correctly. I got confused.

Actually, my table was available in different schema like "dbo.service.tabel1" and it created "dbo.table1" through code first and there was no data in this table which was correct behavior and I was expecting rows.

People can see this possibilities while debugging. Thanks.